# What tele-extender can I use with a Tamron 18-270mm lens on a Canon Rebel?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, tamron, teleconverter

have a Canon EOS Rebel XSI and have a Tamron 18-270mm lens for it. Do you know what extender is compatible with this arrangement? I purchased a Canon Extender EF 2X III but it does not fit the lens.

Answer (score 1):

Using a teleconverter on a a Rebel body with a slow zoom lens is not likely to work well, unfortunately.

Autofocus will not work and image quality is going to be poor. You are much better off saving to buy a longer lens.

Answer (score 0):

The Canon teleconverter (TC) has a lens element that extends out from the barrel and so prevents your current lens from mating to it. What that means is that you need a TC that doesn't extend like that. There are a few, but given that you have a Tamron lens, you might consider the [Tamron 2x TC](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=53247&gclid=CKmvqtrunMQCFQiHaQodfbsAXQ&Q=&is=REG&A=details) as an option. I couldn't find any documentation that said it wouldn't work, but a quick call to their support line should confirm.

Comment: another brand to consider is Kenko. It's likely that autofocus either won't work or will work poorly and slowly, FWIW. And if you can borrow/rent the TC first, do so. you may find image sharpness isn't acceptable.

Comment: The Tamron 2X SP AF Pro and the Kenko Teleplus Pro 300 DGX 2X are the same converter, just marketed separately by each company. They both have 7 elements in 4 groups and share the exact same dimensions and mass. The lower end Tamron F AF 2X (model 230FCA - 4 elements) and Kenko N-AF 2X Teleplus MC7 (7 elements in 4 groups) appear to be different designs.